# Exclude a number in a sequence so that the greatest divisor common of all the other at most. Find the index of the excluded one and that maximum GCD

Tags: c++, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

> Exclude a number in a sequence so that the greatest divisor common of all the other at most. Find the index of the excluded one and that maximum greatest divisor common.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int gcd(int x, int y) {
    while (y) {
        int r=x%y;
        x=y;
        y=r;
    }
    return x;
}
int pcd(int arr[], int u, int w) {
    int temp=arr[u];
    arr[u]=0;
    int result=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=w; i++) {
        result=gcd(result, arr[i]);
    }
    arr[u]=temp;
    return result;
}
int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[100000];
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    int t=0;
    int v;
    for (int j=1; j<=n; j++) {
        if (pcd(a, j, n)>t) {
            t=pcd(a, j, n);
            v=j;
        }
    }
    cout<<v<<" "<<pcd(a, v, n);
}
```

How can I speed up my code ? It's running over the time limit.

Comment: This "assignment" seems to be from some kind of competition site. The problems on such sites are all about using trickery to help solve the problems. Either by finding a single formula where loops aren't needed to calculate the result, or by caching results from previous calculations (in competition-site speak called *dynamic programming*).

Comment: And while you haven't fallen into all of the bad-code traps taught at such sites, you still have some bad habits you need to overcome (even on such sites). Like single-letter variables without semantic meaning, lack of comments, large arrays instead of e.g. `std::vector`, one-based indexing. Just to name a few.

Comment: Actually, "disclude" is a word used in dentistry... To cause (opposing teeth) to fail to meet when the jaws are closed.

Comment: I understand that. I'd used "exclude"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a prefix GCD list and a suffix GCD list by accumulating the result of applying GCD in one direction. Then iterate over the list, checking `GCD(prefix[i], suffix[i])` for the maximum.